# cs50: pset1: credit: Stuck, all cards entered invalid

Tags: c, cs50, fgets

Been working on this problem set for the past few hours and I thought I was doing pretty well, but when I ran it, doesn't really work as expected.
Kinda stuck at the moment, can anyone offer some insight?

**EDIT**
Sorry guys, I'll provide a little more insight on the problem because too little info is provided for it in my post. So basically I have to implement the [Luhn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm). According to Luhn’s algorithm, you can determine if a credit card number is (syntactically) valid as follows:

Multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together.
Add the sum to the sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2.
If the total’s last digit is 0 (or, put more formally, if the total modulo 10 is congruent to 0), the number is valid!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
printf("type a credit card number: ");
char ccnum[17];
fgets(ccnum, 17, stdin);
int ccnumber[15];

int n = strlen(ccnum);

for (int i = 0; i<16; i++)
{
    ccnumber[i] = ccnum[i] -'0';
}


int ccnumber_m[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i+=2)
{
    ccnumber_m[i] = ccnumber[i]*2;
}
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
     if (ccnumber_m[i] > 9)
     {
         sum += (ccnumber_m[i] % 10) + 1;
     }
     else
     {
        sum += ccnumber_m[i];
     }
     printf("%d\n", sum);
}


for (int i = 1; i < 16; i+=2)
{
    sum += ccnumber[i];
}

if (sum%10 == 0)
{
    if ( (n == 15) && (ccnumber[0] == 34 || ccnumber[0] == 37))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if ((n == 16) && (ccnumber[0] == 51 || ccnumber[0] == 52 ||ccnumber[0] == 53 || ccnumber[0] == 54 || ccnumber[0] == 55))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else if ((n == 13 || n == 16) && ccnumber[0] == 4)
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
}    
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

}

I've added a printf to my sum variable to see where the program is failing and that's where things seem to be screwing up. Every time I run it, different values of sum appear?!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example: int ccnumber_m[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i+=2)
{
    ccnumber_m[i] = ccnumber[i]*2;
} - you're accessing `ccnumber_m` out of bounds as it has only 7 elements indexed 0 - 6, yeat you're accessing up to 15... If you're using GCC, compile with `-Wall -Wextra -O3 -fsanitize=undefined,address` to see what funky stuff you're doing...

Comment: With `ccnumber[0] == 34` did you mean `ccnumber[0] == 0x34`? Better to check for the *actual digits* you want: `ccnumber[0] == '4'`. Similarly with `ccnumber[0] == 52` but: you've **already made** the ASCII adjustment in the first loop with `ccnumber[i] = ccnum[i] -'0';`.

Comment: sorry guys, I just edited the problem and provided a little bit more info about it.

Comment: 'ccnumber[i] = ccnum[i] -'0';' writes out-of-bounds for i=15.

Comment: Your code is just full of OOB, range and fencepost obi-wan errors.  How about, everywhere you access an array, you print out the index you are using, so you can check them.

Comment: ..and, unless you are on a RAM-restricted system, stop bean-counting.   If you declare an array with a size less than 128, hit yourself over the head with an accounting manual:)

Comment: Problem solved. Special thanks to @AnttiHaapala and Martin James!

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, found the solution. Yes I messed up most of my loops and the array ranges and the conditions were all over the place. Did some tweaks to my code overall and after a few  more hours, the code works as expected. Here's the updated code.
Pretty sure the code could be more succinct and could be solved much faster. Will take a look at it tomorrow again in order to brainstorm more ideas and find ways to solve it faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
printf("type a credit card number: ");
char ccnum[17];
fgets(ccnum, 17, stdin);
int ccnumber[15];

int n = strlen(ccnum);
int counter = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ccnumber[i] = ccnum[i] -'0';
    if (ccnumber[i] >= 0)
    {
        counter ++;
    }
}
int sum = 0;
if (counter == 16)
{

    int ccnumber_m[7];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = counter - 2; i > -1 ; i-=2, index++)
    {
        ccnumber_m[index] = ccnumber[i]*2;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
         if (ccnumber_m[i] > 9)
         {
             sum += (ccnumber_m[i] % 10) + 1;
         }
         else
         {
            sum += ccnumber_m[i];
         }
    }
     for (int i = 1; i < counter + 1; i+=2)
     {
        sum += ccnumber[i];
     }

}
else if (counter == 15)
{
    int ccnumber_m[6];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = counter-2; i > 0; i-=2, index++)
    {
        ccnumber_m[index] = ccnumber[i]*2;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
         if (ccnumber_m[i] > 9)
         {
             sum += (ccnumber_m[i] % 10) + 1;
         }
         else
         {
            sum += ccnumber_m[i];
         }
    } 
    
     for (int i = 0; i < counter + 1; i+=2)
     {
        sum += ccnumber[i];
     }
}
else if(counter == 13)
{
    int ccnumber_m[5];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = counter-2; i > 0; i-=2, index++)
    {
        ccnumber_m[index] = ccnumber[i]*2;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
         if (ccnumber_m[i] > 9)
         {
             sum += (ccnumber_m[i] % 10) + 1;
         }
         else
         {
            sum += ccnumber_m[i];
         }
    } 
    
     for (int i = 0; i < counter + 1; i+=2)
     {
        sum += ccnumber[i];
     }   
}
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
    return 0;
}


if (sum%10 == 0)
{
    if ((counter == 15) && ((ccnumber[0] == 3 && ccnumber[1] == 4) || (ccnumber[0] == 3 && ccnumber[1] == 7)))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if ((counter == 16) && ((ccnumber[0] == 5 && ccnumber[1] == 1) || (ccnumber[0] == 5 && ccnumber[1] == 2) || (ccnumber[0] == 5 && ccnumber[1] == 3) || (ccnumber[0] == 5 && ccnumber[1] == 4) || (ccnumber[0] == 5 && ccnumber[1] == 5)))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else if ((counter == 13 || counter == 16) && (ccnumber[0] == 4))
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 0;
    }
}    
else
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
    return 0;
}
```

}